# how to remove lines with duplicated substrings from txt file in python?

Tags: python, string

i am trying to remove lines from a .txt file that contains duplicated substrings. lets say i have lines like this:

```
aaaaaa, something.... 
bbbbbb, something differet.. 
cccccc, some other text.. 
cccccc, again different text.. 
dddddd, again some other text..
eeeeee, some other text... 
etc..
```

i want to filter out all the lines that start with the same substring (first N chars), so that there will be only one (the first one) line starting with it. these i want to copy to a new txt file.

so in the example above the first three lines would be copied, the fourth would be skipped and the rest would be copied.

i want to copy all the lines, not only the substring that i am checking

this is what i have written based on what i have found

```
lines_seen = set()
outfile = open(outfile, "w")

for line in open(infile, "r"):
    string_to_compare = line[0:N] #save the substring into a variable
    if line.startswith(string_to_compare) not in lines_seen:
        outfile.write(line)
        lines_seen.add(line)
outfile.close()
```

this code above actually copies all the lines from the outfile into infile, so no filtering is done.

can anyone tell me where is the mistake or how to make it work, please?

Comment: line.startswith returns a boolean

Comment: It would be easier for people to read your question if you put the screenshot into your question inline instead of as a link.

Comment: Slicing the first N characters from a string and then checking if the string startswith that slice is always going to be true...

Comment: yes, that is why i get the exact same copy in the outfile..

Answer (score 1):

If are only interested in the first 60 characters you should store only this slice in your set (`lines_see.add(string_to_compare)`) and your check should be changed to `if string_to_compare not in lines_seen:`.

Comment: no, i am not interested only in the first 60 chars - i want to copy all the lines and these first 60 chars serve as a filter to check, whether a particular line (that was already copied) contains this substring - if so, no other copy is needed

Comment: @NirvikalpaSamadhi so how does this answer not help you?

Comment: it actually seems that it did help. sorry, was little bit confused.. thank you guys!